# How does the arity.jar arithmetic library evaluates an operation String?

Tags: java, eval

Hi everyone I recently came across the Arity library -> [source can be found here](https://code.google.com/r/vetohin87-arity/source/browse/src/org/javia/arity/Symbols.java?r=76e4ea9090f252e2b03982639d582460d4558588)
And found that it evaluates a String as an Arithmetic operation using an *.eval()* method, looking at the source I found this method of the Symbols object:

```
/**
       Evaluates a simple expression (such as "1+1") and returns its value.
       @throws SyntaxException in these cases:
       <ul>
       <li> the expression is not well-formed
       <li> the expression is a definition (such as "a=1+1")
       <li> the expression is an implicit function (such as "x+1")
       </ul>
     */
    public synchronized double eval(String expression) throws SyntaxException {
        return compiler.compileSimple(this, expression).eval();
    }
```

This method calls the .compileSimple of the Compiler compile object:

```
Function compileSimple(Symbols symbols, String expression) throws SyntaxException {
    rpn.setConsumer(simpleCodeGen.setSymbols(symbols));
    lexer.scan(expression, rpn);
    return simpleCodeGen.getFun();
}
```

Which returns a Function object and then calls the eval() method on that. Looking at the Function.eval() method I saw this:

```
/**
       Evaluates an arity-0 function (a function with no arguments).
       @return the value of the function
    */
    public double eval() {
        throw new ArityException(0);
    }
```

The method eval must return a double type and the implementation throws an ArityException which has this implementation:

```
public class ArityException extends RuntimeException {
    public ArityException(String mes) {
        super(mes);
    }

    public ArityException(int nArgs) {
        this("Didn't expect " + nArgs + " arguments");
    }
}
```

But when the ArityException is thrown it calls the super() constructor of the RuntimeException, and this is an exception and no double returned as it should, maybe I have mess some passages, but I didn't understand the last throw new ArityException of 0 inside the Function.eval() implementation.

So how does it really works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the declaration of `simpleCodeGen`:

```
private final SimpleCodeGen simpleCodeGen = new SimpleCodeGen(exception);
```

That means that `compileSimple(...)` actually returns a `CompiledFunction`, which extends `ContextFunction` and such `Function`.

```
CompiledFunction getFun() {
    return new CompiledFunction(0, code.toArray(), consts.getRe(), consts.getIm(), funcs.toArray());
}
```

So actually it's the `eval(...)` function in `ContextFunction` that is being called. That one has a real implementation.

Doing a code analysis without an IDE and just watching the code can be tricky. Using a debugger and stepping through would easily show you the program flow.

Comment: Thank you for having it explained!